# XSLT - how to get value of tag if attribute equals a specific value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to get different values according an attribute of a different tag.
my xml input:

```
<parties>
    <party code="ADV" id="BOFAUS3NXXX" extension="1">
        <name1>BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.</name1>
        <city>Code: NY3-222-14-03</city>
        <street>Bank of America Merrill Lynch Mail</street>
        <country>US</country>
        <swift_address/>
    </party>
    <party code="BNE" id="11111111-1" extension="1">
        <name1>BBA Customer 1</name1>
        <city>PROVIDENCIA</city>
        <street>PROVIDENCIA 1645</street>
        <country>ES</country>
        <swift_address/>
    </party>
</parties>
```

I'm trying to get the value inside `name1` if the `party/@code = "ADV"`.

I have tried to use the following expression and it doesn't work:

```
<xsl:if test="value-of select=("ns1:parties/ns1:party/@code")='ADV'">
    <td>1st Advising Bank Name: <xsl:value-of select="ns1:parties/ns1:party/name1/></td>
</xsl:if>
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is this

```
<xsl:if test="parties/party/@code='ADV'">
   <td>1st Advising Bank Name: <xsl:value-of select="parties/party[@code='ADV']/name1" /></td>
</xsl:if>
```

Note, I have excluded the `ns1` namespace prefix here, because the XML sample shown does not have any namespaces declared.

Alternatively, use template matching. Use `xsl:apply-templates` to select the matching `party` element

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="parties/party[@code='ADV']" />
```

Then have a template to match it

```
<xsl:template match="party">
   <td>1st Advising Bank Name: <xsl:value-of select="name1" /></td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks @Tim C the condition   <xsl:if test="parties/party/@code='ADV'"> works but the value-of of doesn't:    <td>1st Advising Bank Name: <xsl:value-of select="parties/party/name1" /></td> since i have two tags that can refer to "parties/party/name1" . is there a way to retrieve the value of specific tag . something like  <xsl:value-of select="ns1:parties/ns1:party[@code='ADV']/name1" /> which doesn't really works

Comment: The expression `<xsl:value-of select="parties/party[@code='ADV']/name1" />` should work. I've amended my answer to show this expression. It would be preferable to try and use template matching in this case. That way you change your context to the relevant `party` element, and so the expressions will then be relative to that.

Comment: Thanks Tim but it doesn't work for me. is it legal to have tag after checking if attribute is equal?

Comment: The syntax is correct, but it is possible that it is to do with namespaces. Your XML does not have namespaces, but by using the prefix `ns1` in your XSLT sample, it suggests your actual XML does have them. Perhaps you just need the `ns1` prefix before `name` in the path too? `<xsl:value-of select="ns1:parties/ns1:party[@code='ADV']/ns1:name1" />`